# Parent container margin effecting the child margin

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am working on drawing a rectangle shape on a browser using divs on React project. Everything is working as expected but when I am adding the margin to the parent `base` and then drawing the box the boxes are drawing with some space between the mouse courser and the actual box.

The same thing happening if I am adding a top margin to a `base`

Here is my code:

```
 const divRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
    const [mousedown, setMouseDown] = useState(false);
    const [last_mousex, set_last_mousex] = useState(0);
    const [last_mousey, set_last_mousey] = useState(0);
    const [mousex, set_mousex] = useState(0);
    const [mousey, set_mousey] = useState(0);
    const [rectx, setrectx] = useState(0);
    const [recty, setrecty] = useState(0);
    const [rectwidth, setrectwidth] = useState(0);
    const [rectheight, setrectheight] = useState(0);
    const [visual, setVisualRect] = useState(false);

    const mouseDown = (event: any) => {
        set_last_mousex(event.clientX);
        set_last_mousey(event.clientY);
        setMouseDown(true);
    };

    const mouseMove = (event: any) => {
        set_mousex(event.clientX);
        set_mousey(event.clientY);
        visualRect();
    };

    const visualRect = () => {
        if (mousedown) {
            const width = Math.abs(mousex - last_mousex);
            const height = Math.abs(mousey - last_mousey);
            const rx = mousex < last_mousex ? mousex : last_mousex;
            const ry = mousey < last_mousey ? mousey : last_mousey;
            rectx !== rx && setrectx(rx);
            recty !== ry && setrecty(ry);
            rectheight !== height && setrectheight(height);
            rectwidth !== width && setrectwidth(width);
            setVisualRect(true);
        }
      };

    const mouseUp = () => {
        setMouseDown(false);
        setVisualRect(false);
    };

    return (
        <div className={"base"}>
            <div className={"container"} ref={divRef}>
                <div
                    className={"drawArea"}
                    onMouseDown={mouseDown}
                    onMouseUp={mouseUp}
                    onMouseMove={mouseMove}
                >
                    {visual && 
                        (<div className={"rectBox"} style={{left: rectx, top: recty, width:rectwidth, height:rectheight}}></div>)
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
```

Here is the CSS:

```
.base {
  width: 600px;
  height: 500px;
  /* this margin is causing issue */
  margin-left: 200px;
}

.drawArea {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.rectBox {
  position: absolute;
  border: 3px solid #581d1d;
}

.container {
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgb(219, 219, 219);
  position: relative;
}
```

I also created sandbox [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-forked-jpk8t2?file=/src/styles.css:0-366)

Comment: `event.clientX` and `event.clientY` are relative to the viewport, so if you move your elements around using margins, you need to compensate for that offset.

Comment: same thing happening with ```pageX``` and ```pageY```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@CBroe is correct, clientX and clientY is relative to viewport.
What you can do is subtract it from the element's viewport X & Y so you get the proper coordinates relative to the element's X & Y

For example, if the element's X is `200px` and the click is `245px`, both relative to viewport, if you compute `245px - 200px` you get `45px` which is relative to the element because you got rid of the element's X from the click's X.

```
  const mouseDown = (event: any) => {
    const x = event.clientX - event.currentTarget.getBoundingClientRect().left
    const y = event.clientY - event.currentTarget.getBoundingClientRect().top
    set_last_mousex(x);
    set_last_mousey(y);
    setMouseDown(true);
  };

  //... 
  
  const mouseMove = (event: any) => {
    const x = event.clientX - event.currentTarget.getBoundingClientRect().left
    const y = event.clientY - event.currentTarget.getBoundingClientRect().top
    set_mousex(x);
    set_mousey(y);
    visualRect();
  };
```

`getBoundingClientRect`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect